# Error parsing d3 line chart 2d data

Tags: d3.js

Why is this getting this error:

```
Error: Problem parsing d="MNaN,NaNLNaN,NaN"
```

Line chart:

```
var data = [ [5, 20], [80, 90], [250, 50], [100, 33], [330, 95],
            [410, 12], [475, 44], [25, 67], [85, 21], [220, 88] ];

var margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 50},
                width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
                height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var x = d3.scale.linear()
                .domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d[0]; }))
                .range(0, width);
var y = d3.scale.linear()
                .domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d[1]; }))
                .range(0, height);

var line = d3.svg.line()
                .x(function(d) { return x(d[0]) })
                .y(function(d) { return y(d[1]) });

var svg = d3.select("body")
            .append("svg")
            .attr("height", height)
            .attr("width", width);

svg.append("path")
    .data(data)
    .attr("class", "line")
    .attr("d", line);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There're two small problems with your code. First, the range of a scale needs to be specified as a two-element array, i.e. instead of

```
.range(0, width)
```

do

```
.range([0, width])
```

Secondly, you need to pass the data in as a one-element array (as there's only a single line), i.e.

```
svg.append("path")
   .data([data])
```

Complete jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/7dhxj/).